# Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\MovieType" given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpstorm, symfony-forms

I am stuck with that error :/

Where is the problem? I am pretty new to symfony with PHP... would be nice if someone could help me with that:)

```
class MovieType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array                      $options)
{
    $builder->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('samsCharacterName', TextType::class)
            ->add('isMainCharacter', CheckboxType::class, array(
                required => false
            ))
            ->add('rating', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('releasedAt', DateType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Movie'
    ));
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_bundle_movie_type';
}

}
```

Comment: Is not clear where the error is raised or where you are using in this manner, anyway check that you are creating with the `::class` notation as example:     `$form = $this->createForm(MovieType::class, $movie);`

Answer (score 2):

Is not clear where the error is raised or where you are using in this manner, anyway check that you are creating with the `::class` notation as example:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MovieType::class, $movie);
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) in the doc.

Hope this help